# Enable/Disable the kafka binding in spring cloud stream using properties

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Is there any property that enables/disables the kafka binding in spring cloud stream . I would like to leave the kafka binder  inclusion  in the the pom.xml but  would like to disable/enable the kafka binding optionally in production . if there is no such property available , appreciate any pointers to achieve this (perhaps via some java configuration or  @Conditional* annotations) .

Why do we need this :

We are migrating one of our application from a oracle db/JMS infrastructure to Mongo/Kafka infrastructure. WE will be running  both of  these version of the app in  parallel  for sometime  for validation. We are maintaining the same source base for both ,by having separate dao and controller layers and keeping a common service layer. The idea is to deploy both versions of the app generated from the same source base (current and migrated) and run them parallel for  sometime for validation. When we do that current version need not be  aware of any kafka/mongo connection parameters and  migrated version need not be aware of any oracle/JMS connection paramters . We are able achieve this for oracle/mongo  using service binding and @Conditional* annotations . But for the Spring cloud stream for kafka we are using the following properties  which always requires valid parameters where the kafka connection can be made.

- spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers
- spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes

Comment: I am still struggling to understand what would such an application do in prod if it is not bound to anything? Is there something else that the application does? And if so, why are you pairing the "something else" which is out of scope of spring-cloud-stream architecturally together with messaging code which is in scope of spring-cloud-stream? I am just trying to understand your architecture.

Comment: The requirement is elaborated  in the question . I hope that clarifies your question  @oleg-zhurakousky

Comment: I see. . . You can probably tinker with overrides as well, or may be simply remove the binder dependency all together for the time being. At this point I guess it is safe to say the framework was not designed with that use case in mind especially given the "opinionated" paradigms adopted from boot.
Consider raising an issue in spring-cloud-stream Github and we can continue this discussion there and if we want to consider adding it as a feature.

Comment: A  feature request is created in github

Answer (score 1):

It can be disabled from the Spring Boot Application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
 ...
}
```

From the application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```